# Ajax Javascript - POST method 'u' is an invalid start of a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html page for Login function that keep returning me the error 400 above. No matter what I input.

My html code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnLogin').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/User/LoginAsync',
      method: 'POST',

      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: {
        userName: $('#txtUsername').val(),
        password: $('#txtPassword').val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response);
        window.location.href = "UserAccountPage.html";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username..." /><br />
<input type="text" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password..." /><br />
<input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login" />
```

My api

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error ?

Comment: Site won't let me edit so here's my error https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIkU.png

Comment: This looks like a server-side error. Some validation is not passed. I would take a look at the server-side validators.

Comment: You need to contact server side for this error. they can only tell you the actual reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining the AJAX call with XML parameters, but you are passing JSON format in the API Tester

The correct AJAX call must be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnLogin').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/User/LoginAsync',
      method: 'POST',

      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        userName: $('#txtUsername').val(),
        password: $('#txtPassword').val()
      }),
      success: function(response) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response);
        window.location.href = "UserAccountPage.html";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The contentType involves only the AJAX Call results (it expects a JSON in the response)